# Most efficient index system

Tags: mysql

I have the following table and I want to know how I can make the most efficient index system for this table on selects.  The rows will never be updated once they are inserted.

```
CREATE TABLE `games_characters` (
  `game_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `character_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `games` (`game_id`),
  KEY `characters` (`character_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

or would something like this be better:

```
CREATE TABLE `games_characters` (
  `game_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `character_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY `game_to_characters` (`game_id`, `character_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

or is there a third and better option?

There will never be more than 10 `games_characters` to a single `game` and once again they will not change once inserted.

Thanks

Comment: If there are only 10 entries to a table, is efficiency really a consideration? Maybe I'm too practical? Why do you care?

Comment: Why not a composite primary key for `game_characters`?

Comment: @Floris 10 rows per game_id, not 10 rows in a table, the table will fill up very fast with a few million rows at least

Comment: @njk How would I go about this?  I'm not too familiar with the different KEYs in mysql, only what i've seen in other examples of things

Comment: @MasterGberry Your second option is better; however the columns can't be `DEFAULT NULL`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess second option would work properly. BUT if game_id and character_id wolud be a primary key they cant be "DEFAULT NULL".
I hope it was helpful.

EDIT: MyISAM engine is fast for queries.

Comment: right, they won't ever be null, that's my bad.  the two values would always work.  So the second is more efficient than the first?

Comment: if you need a composite primary key , yes. I mean, there can't be a duplicate character who belong to the same game id. Besides, you will only have 10 characters, per game and myisam, as i said, works fast for queries.

Comment: That is an interesting point...depending on the game mode it is indeed possible for there to be duplicate characters at times...may create two different tables depending on mode...thanks

Comment: You could do something: game_id as primary key(as a pk it's already indexed) and then add an index to character_id and then you won't need to create another table and both columns would be 'indexed' and you could have as many duplicated character_id per game_id as you wanted. :-)

Comment: I was always the impression that a PRIMARY KEY must be unique, am I wrong to assume this?

Comment: You're not wrong. A primary key is a unique column. But what i said above doesn't mean the pk would allow duplicated records.

Comment: I'm not understanding something properly then, can you take your last suggestion and edit your post with the exact syntax?  Thanks

Comment: Excuse me, i was a little bit distracted. What i said makes no sense. The second answer i posted is the right way to achieve this.

CREATE TABLE GAMES_CHARACTERS(
GAME_ID INT(11),
CHARACTER_ID INT(11),
PRIMARY KEY(GAME_ID,CHARACTER_ID)

Or if you say you may need to duplicate some characters you could create a link table as you just expressed.
I don`t know what are you developing but a table for game information, other table for characters information, and the link table containing characters per game(this would allow duplicated records) would be a nice idea.
I hope it works for you